# Having an image showed nice when the page zoom is more than 100%

Tags: css, image

I have an icon showed on my page. When the page zoom is 100% (in the navigator) the icon is pretty nice, but when the zoom is bigger like 150% the icon is blurry. See below. How can I avoid this? Maybe having a bigger icon and reduce it at 50% (intentionally) when showing it in a < img ... > and then when the page zoom is bigger the icon may be less blurry? I don't know if I'm clear...

[image]

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: So what happens at 200%?

Comment: It is blurry at higher zoom level. i think a good solution may be to use SVG icons but I don't know how to reference it in an html page.

Comment: Did you test your maybe?  This question comes down to "Will the browser take advantage of the higher res original, or just scale up the rendered version.  I think the answer is no, it will just scale up the rendered version.  Why not just test this and find out?

Comment: Browser zoom is a strange beast. Each one works slightly differently.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you want an image to not be blurred when zoomed in?

As far as I know, a browser will just enlarge the image on zoom, therefore you will just need to create a larger image. If you want it to be a fixed size at 100%, simply add the width and height attributes to the 'img' tag.

Comment: If your image is a simple icon you could use SVG.

Comment: How can I show an icon of SVG format? Just like an ordinary image in an img tag?

Answer (score 0):

this may sound stupid, but how about using a larger image, but with the same width and height of the current one?
The quality should stay good until zoomed more than the size of the actual image.